# Regex, select link whats start from space, but exclude space from selection

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regexp like this

```
((?:^|\s)https?:\/\/[^\s]+|(?:^|\s)www\.[^\s]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/TwD0S3/2

it must match all link in text whats starts from space, or have nothing before them, and everything is fine, but space (if it exist) must be excluded from matched link. Is it possible at all?
Link in html code must not be matched, so

```
<img src="http://link.dev/static/images/svg/logo.svg">
```

must be ignored at all.

Regexp will be used in JavaScript

Comment: No, "> must not be matched

Comment: Well, try [`/\b(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\s<>"']+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/iMkCqu/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew everthing is perfect, but matches link what starts from " !

Comment: So, you just need [`(?:^|\s)((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\s<>"']+)`](https://regex101.com/r/iMkCqu/3) and get Group 1 contents.

Comment: @OP Your regex link seems to work

Comment: Or a better idea: use `/<[^<]*>|((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+)/g` to match the tags, but only capture the URLs outside of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a capturing group to grab the contents you are interested in. To make your regex work, just wrap the part from `http` with `(` and `)`. Also, it can be enhanced a bit to make matching more linear:

```
/(?:^|\s)((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\s<>"']+)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ict4sj/1), the string you need is inside Group 1.

```js
var rx = /(?:^|\s)((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\s<>"']+)/ig;
var str = 'http://link.dev/static/images/svg/logo1.svg\n<img src="http://link.dev/static/images/svg/logo2.svg">\nthis is simple text www.link.dev/static/images/svg/logo3.svg \nor https://link.dev/static/images/svg/logo4.svg';
var res=[],m;

while ((m = rx.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(res);
```

However, to avoid matching URLs in between `<` and `>`, you may just match these substrings with `<[^<]*>` (add it as an alternative branch using `|` alternation operator), and capture the URLs everywhere else ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iMkCqu/4)):

```
/<[^<]*>|((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+)/gi
```

```js
var rx = /<[^<]*>|((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+)/gi;
var str = 'http://link.dev/static/images/svg/logo1.svg\n<img src="http://link.dev/static/images/svg/logo2.svg">\nthis is simple text www.link.dev/static/images/svg/logo3.svg \nor https://link.dev/static/images/svg/logo4.svg';
var res=[],m;

while ((m = rx.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m[1]) res.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(res);
```